# How to change UITableView Label to multiple color in Swift4

Tags: ios, uitableview, colors, label, swift4

How do I change the text in my UITableView to two different colors?

```
    let highest = (history[indexPath.row].highest!)   //Red color
    let lowest = (history[indexPath.row].lowest!)     //Green color
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "$\(highest)/$\(lowest)"

    return cell
```

Thank you!

Comment: use attributed text for this use two colors one for lowest and other highest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your output will look like that :

[image]

you can do it simply like that

```
    //your constants
    let highest = (history[indexPath.row].highest!)   //Red color
    let lowest = (history[indexPath.row].lowest!)     //Green color

    // a string combining them 
    let concatOfHighestLowest = "$\(highest)/$\(lowest)"

    //the attributed mutable string .
    let finalString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: concatOfHighestLowest)
     // 1 in NSRange Locations stands for the "$" symbol.
    finalString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location:1,length:highest.count))
     // highest.count + 3 in NSRange stands for the "$ , /" symbols and after the highest value.
    finalString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.green, range: NSRange(location:highest.count + 3,length:lowest.count))




    cell.detailTextLabel?.attributedText = finalString

    return cell
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSMutableAttributedString`

```
let myString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "$\(highest)/$\(lowest)" )
let heighestRange = myString.mutableString.range(of: highest)
myString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: heighestRange)
let lowestRange = myString.mutableString.range(of: lowest)
myString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.green, range: lowestRange)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    func setColor(color: UIColor, forText stringValue: String) {
        let range: NSRange = self.mutableString.range(of: stringValue, options: .caseInsensitive)
        self.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range)
    }

}
```

By using the above extension you can set text color for label like below

```
    let highest = "160"   //Red color
    let lowest = "80"     //Green color
    let stringValue = "$\(highest)/$\(lowest)"
    let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
    attributedString.setColor(color: UIColor.red, forText: highest)
    attributedString.setColor(color: UIColor.green, forText: lowest)
    self.testLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Output Will be like below

[image]